# How to configure idle period for auto locking screen

Tags: 12.04, settings, lock-screen

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin).

I noticed that, there is no screensaver settings, which is fine. I like to control the period of time after which the blank screen is shown,which automatically locks the screen.

I do not want to enable screensaver. I only wish to be able to change the idle time period required to lock the screen automatically. It seems to me, it is by default around 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hi yes this is in the `System Setting -> Brightness and Lock`

[image]

Then you can change the amount of time to turn the screen off.

[image]

Comment: Also ... other Linux variations have this under screen saver settings.

Comment: do you know where to find this setting in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

system setting ---workspace -->desktop behavior--Screen Locking

I have solved my problem using in KDE desktop. Please try this

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Power -> Power Saving

[image]

[image]