# repeatedly asked for admin password

Tags: password, malware

With a brand-new Ubuntu 14.04 installation I streamed the third period of a hockey  game last night.  It was literally the first time I used this new computer.  It connected to wifi no problem, and stayed connected, but every five minutes the browser window would disappear and I was presented with the login page that you see when you turn the computer on, and asked for my admin password.  as there seemed to be no way around it to get back to using the computer, I entered the password each time.

Now I'm worrying that I just authorized the installation of malware.  Very computer-illiterate here, but simply knowing enough to know that windows has always been very annoying and ubuntu is much more simple and elegant.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be related to no activity on the keyboard or mouse and the system locking the screen for security like in this Q&A: [Brightness & Lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155058/how-to-configure-idle-period-for-auto-locking-screen)