# Automatic keyboard input to Linux system

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard

I am using a Linux system.
The X-Window will be closed if keyboard idles for 5 minutes.
One way to avoid the closure of X-Window is to press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key within 5 minutes.
My question: Is there an automatic way to "press" <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key from keyboard?

I tried the following command from a script but failed:

```
echo -ne "\r" > /dev/myTTY
```

or

```
echo -ne "\n" > /dev/myTTY
```

The newline or CR appears in the command line, but system did not seems to have received the command.

Comment: See this question http://askubuntu.com/q/155058/108339

Answer (score 1):

Try using xdotool

Start of by installing xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then create the following script and run it at startup.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    sleep 300
    xdotool  key Return
done
```

All this does is waits 300 seconds, then presses the Enter key, then repeats.

If you do not want to save this as a file, you can simply type the exact same code line by line in to a terminal window and it would do the exact same thing until you close the terminal.